# Is there any replacement for Prelude's iterate function in classy prelude?

Tags: haskell, classy-prelude

In the standard prelude:

```
Prelude> :t iterate
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

However, in classy prelude there is no iterate, so I presume there might be some more generic function to do the same, perhaps a monadic one. I just cannot figure out what it is. Is there one?

Comment: Generalized anamorphisms (like `iterate` or `unfold`) are less common than generalized catamorphisms (like `map` or `fold`). It think it's more likely `iterate` was omitted because it isn't used commonly enough to warrant inclusion in a redesigned prelude.

Answer (score 2):

You can always reimplement it with [`ClassyPrelude.repeat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-1.0.2/docs/ClassyPrelude.html#v:repeat) and [`Data.List.scanl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanl):

```
iterate = \f a -> scanl (\a f -> f a) a (repeat f)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `\f -> unfoldr (Just . join (,) . f)`